# android anyctask blocks activity

Tags: android, android-activity, download, android-asynctask, block

I am working on a project that lists items that users can click on any of them and see its detail in detailsActivity and if they like it so the can download it! i am using asynctask to list all the items from server in the doBackgournd method and display the result in onPostExecute method. The problem is when users start a download and go back to the list and click on another item the detail of the item is displayed only when the first download finishes!

I want the users be able to choose any item and go the detailsActivity while the download is running for other items they previously started.

please help

Comment: please add code otherwise we cant' help you

Answer (score 0):

You should try and place your download to a Service.
[A Service is an application component that can perform long-running operations in the background and does not provide a user interface.](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: you can tell this as a comment,

Comment: He can't, not enough rep points. It happened to me too, sometimes I wanted to answer something in comments but had to use a full answer. Quite annoying really.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask in (earlier versions after android 3.0 I think) android works sequentialy by default
if you want to change this behavior you can use executeOnExcuter instead of execute
for example

```
task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```